# Secondary citation: prevent cited references in document to display in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, multiple-citations

I have been looking over and over again, yet the only answers I find are for the opposite demand (*i.e.*, how to print un-cited references in bibliography).

As I am referencing a secondary citation, and that Zotero does not yet handle that, I found a workaround. Citing one ref then append text like “quoted in” and then cite the author ref. Example:

```
\autocites{muddeEuropePopulistSurge2016}[quoted in][287]{tanselNeoliberalismAntagonismsAuthoritarian2019}
```

Now, I do not want Mudde Cas (bib key `muddeEuropePopulistSurge2016`) to be printed in the bibliography. What command would do the trick?

P.S.: It’s not regarding just secondary citation. It’s more about how  not to print a cited ref in the bibliography. Another use case is when you cite a whole book, and then you cite a specific section of the book. I’m not able to produce the desired Chicago style outcome for citing a book section. ([see here](https://www.trentu.ca/academicskills/documentation-guide/chicago-style/bibliography/chicago-style-citing-book-sections)) So I need create a different biblatex entry for the book section, and then cite it. But in the bibliography, I do not want to print the book section as I already have printed the whole book.